# Cordova: app not working anymore on ios since few months with cordova-sms-plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, sms

I know android and ios development but not Cordova.
I retrieve an app in my firm which worked fine on both platforms, but for several months, it crashes on iPhone, without changing anything.

The crash happens when a button is clicked to send an sms with the plugin https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin. And after building and testing, I found the exemption

> NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.'

Generally, it resolves with something like

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {}
```

But there is no native code, only one MainViewController with generic code.

How it's possible the ios app crashed overnight and how can I solve the problem?
I updated all the plugins and checked if anything change in the plugin recommendations, but everything looks good.

Thank you

Comment: Run a build of your app under the Xcode debugger with the main thread checker enabled and see where the crash occurs.

Comment: It seems the plugin was not well updated since by copy paste the content of Sms.m, it works fine